# WordPress sort wp_query multiple meta_values

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to sort my post and tried nearly everything to make it work.. but no luck :-(

In my loop is a custom post type called deal and expired deal (meta_value through ACF) posts. I want to show the normal posts first and then the expired posts.

This is my code so far:

```
            $args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_type' => 'deal',
                'orderby'   => 'date',
                'order'     => 'DESC',
                'post__not_in' => array($not_in),

            );
```

Any ideas how I can put the "expired" posts behind the normal posts?

Comment: Both order and orderby take arrays ...

Comment: what do you mean? iam no good at php

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is set orderby to meta_value and meta_key to your custom field.

```
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'deal',
            'meta_key'  => 'YOURCUSTOMFIELDHERE',
            'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
            'order'     => 'DESC',
            'post__not_in' => array($not_in),
        );
```

If the DESC order is the wrong direction you can switch it to ASC.